# Managing client accounts in a project already using Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I am developing a WebAPI over my already existant MVC application, using the OAuth2 authorization system.

This API will allow my clients to request my users information. Currently, my users are stored in the Identity tables (ASPNetUsers). In my application, they are registering, logging in, etc... with the help of the Identity classes and methods.

The problem is here : I want to manage my API clients accounts, in an "Identity way", so I can authenticate them when they ask for Access Tokens. But I can't use the current users tables, as there is no common points between my clients and my users.

The perfect solution would be to have two Identity tables : one for my users, and one for my clients, but after my long-time searches, I figured it was not possible, or it would be a mess, at best.

Answer (score 0):

**I would not use ASP.NET Identity as a way to manage OAuth2 registered client applications**. Even though some client applications (confidential) are indeed issued client credentials that's probably the only thing they share with a username/password user identity. **It's a completely different thing and as such it should be managed and stored independently.**

If you're thinking that this sounds like a lot of work, you're absolutely right. It isn't trivial to implement a custom username/password authentication that proves secure and implementing an OAuth2 authorization server is many times as complex.

If you really want/need to go that route then some mandatory reading:

- [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
- [OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819)
- [JSON Web Token (JWT)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) (assuming you choose JWT as token format)

If you're still evaluating all your options I would also consider the possibility of delegating all the authentication/authorization work onto a third-party, Auth0 comes to mind, but I'm biased because I work there.

Comment: What could be a free solution to authenticate my clients ? Unfortunately I can't afford Auth0 for my project...

Comment: It's not free, you'll still have the costs of implementing them in your system, but you can evaluate the if open source stuff like ASOS and IdentityServer suits you better.